# com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.button.Button vs android.widget.Button

Tags: android, android-things

I am new to Java / Android. I am trying to use both screen "Buttons" from android.widget.Button and com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.button.Button for taking inputs from both HW and Visual buttons. The Android Studio does not allow to import both packages due to the same name. I use these direct naming.

```
mButtonInputDriver = new ButtonInputDriver(BoardDefaults.getGPIOForButton(),com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.button.Button.LogicState.PRESSED_WHEN_LOW, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE);
mButtonInputDriver.register();
```

They are still getting called as one. ie; HW button and current active screen button clicks are taken as one. How do I separate these two from each other?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the Hardware button to feed into the normal button mechanism for Android (i.e. the InputDriver feature). Then you should use the `Button` library directly:

```
mButton = new Button(gpioPinName,
        Button.LogicState.PRESSED_WHEN_LOw
);
mButton.setOnButtonEventListener(new OnButtonEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onButtonEvent(Button button, boolean pressed) {
        // do something awesome when the Hardware button is pressed only
    }
});
```

https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/tree/master/button

(Instead of registering with the system using `ButtonInputDriver`)

Comment: The ButtonInputDrived feeds futtons into onKeyPressed, that has nothing to do with the standard View.OnClickedListener of View Buttons. In fact they are completely different things. I actually do not understand this question.